# android: getView() problem - it changes items while scrolling

Tags: android, android-adapter

I made a listview that has three textviews and a checkbox and put it into a BaseAdapter. What it has to do is if an item is at the '**unread**' status, then make its textviews **BOLD**. However, I encountered two problems.

1. the top item is always **BOLD** no matter it is read or unread.
2. If I do scrolling, then items **reloaded** by scrolling start to be bold

I researched about it but couldn't find any good things for me. If anyone has an idea, would you please help me? Below is getView().

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            ViewHolder viewHolder;

            if(convertView == null){ // check if convertView exists
                // get and inflate layout
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.tv1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_callerIDname);
                viewHolder.tv2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_callerIDnumber);
                viewHolder.tv3 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_messageSentTime);
                viewHolder.cb = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

                // get each CheckBox into cb_array for future use
                this.cb_array[position] = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

                // use it as a tag
                view.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            else{
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
            }

            viewHolder.tv1.setText(this.callerIDnames[position]);
            viewHolder.tv2.setText(this.callerIDnumbers[position]);
            viewHolder.tv3.setText(this.messageSentTimes[position]);

            // if message is unread, then make texts bold
            if (messageRead_list[position] == false){
                viewHolder.tv1.setTypeface(viewHolder.tv1.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
                viewHolder.tv2.setTypeface(viewHolder.tv2.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
                viewHolder.tv3.setTypeface(viewHolder.tv3.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
            }

            return view;
        }
```

Comment: I just solved the problem. What I changed was just putting 'null' parameter into the first parameter of 'setTypeface' like 'tv1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL)' It didn't matter when making it bold but did to make its style back to normal.

I appreciate your help. Thank you all! p.s. Unless something else happens, I'll make this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to pass `null` in `setTypeFace()` instead of using `getTypeFace()`.

When `getTypeFace()` doesn't return `null` the style wont be set correctly.

```
// if message is unread, then make texts bold
if (messageRead_list[position] == false){
    viewHolder.tv1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    viewHolder.tv2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    viewHolder.tv3.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
} else {
    viewHolder.tv1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
    viewHolder.tv2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
    viewHolder.tv3.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
}
```

Or you could use this directly which is what's done when you pass `null`.

```
setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
```

and

```
setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.NORMAL));
```

Comment: Hi, rochdev. Thank you for your answer. I see there's a way to use 'Typeface.defaultFromStyle()' method instead of passing 'null' parameter. And really thank you for the explanation that I see why I need to set 'null' value.

Answer (score 1):

When the ListView reuses a view, it may have been bold before scrolling and should be plain now. Try explicitly setting the typeface to PLAIN when the message is read.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ted. I just made an 'else' command to set typeface to 'Typeface.NORMAL' but it doesn't work. The first top one item is still bold and others become bold when scrolling. If you don't mind, would you give me more advice?

Answer (score 0):

You should use two types of view counts by implementing getItemViewType(int position)

like this:

```
public int getViewTypeCount () {
    return 2;
}
```

and this:

```
public int getItemViewType (int position) {
    if (messageRead_list[position] == false) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

and then checking the item type when you create them to set the proper typeface.

this is hack though, I'm setting the type to normal or default when on else as your comment should be the solution. Are you certain that messageRead_list is correct?

Comment: Hello, renam. Thanks for your comment. However, if you don't mind, would you explain what I should do in detail?(or if you give me a code, I would be very grateful) I see one of your methods is to check whether it is read or not but can't understand why and how I use it. In addition, I checked my messageRead_list and other lists are correct. The only problem I have is making textview bold. Thank you for your comment again